# PostgreSQL synchronous and asynchronous replication per specific tables

Tags: postgresql

I have a primary PostgreSQL database with 2 tables, `A` and `B`. I also have a secondary replica database for the disaster recovery. Table `A` updated once in a while, while table `B` updated more frequently. Is it possible to configure PostgreSQL to synchronously replicate table `A` from primary to the secondary database, but asynchronously replicated table `B` into the secondary database? or the replication is per database and can't be configured per tables?